# Giving root access to every user with path based authorization in visual SVN

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've setup the SVN for an office to share all the official documents, projects, policies, etc. To do that I've setup a virtual machine in cloud with Windows 8 and Installed Visual SVN on it.

After Setup, i made repository and configure all the directories and users with path based authorization.

The directory structure is like

- repositoryName

  - rootName

    - Management
    - Policies
    - Training
    - Projects

Where Team Member have access to Projects Directory and Sales persons have access to Management and Directory. Now the problem is to give a **common URL** to all the users from where they view all the directories they are authorized to read/read-write.

I've read all the documentation of Visual SVN but they dont provide any information to implement this.

In Short :

Common URL as per above directory structure can be
https://some.ip.address/repositoryName/rootName/

User Group : Developer, Sales_Person

Users in Developer user group should see

- repositoryName

  - rootName

    - Policies
    - Projects

Users in Sales_Person user group should see

- repositoryName

  - rootName

    - Management
    - Policies